# static import user define package in other package in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Here's another question:

```
package p1;

public class Temp {
    public static int x=10;
    public static void show(){
    System.out.println("hello from show");
    }
}
```

Here is my second file's code:

```
package p2;

import p1.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Temp.x);
        Temp.show();
        out.println(Temp.x + "hello");

    }
}
```

Now this program is working and the output is:

```
10
hello from show
10hello
```

I try to import a user defined package to the other package, and my class path is set. Java rules say that when use import a class static than all the method and data member can accessed without using a class name.

```
package p2;

import static p1.Temp;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
        show();
        out.println(x + "hello");

    }
}
```

I got this error. Why can't I import a user defined package to the other package?

```
    C:\java\static_import>javac -d . StaticImport.java
StaticImport.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import static p1.Temp;
              ^
  symbol: class p1
StaticImport.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static p1.Temp;
^
StaticImport.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(x);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable x
  location: class StaticImport
StaticImport.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                show();
                ^
  symbol:   method show()
  location: class StaticImport
StaticImport.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                out.println(x + "hello");
                            ^
  symbol:   variable x
  location: class StaticImport
5 errors
```

Comment: Only types can be imported with `static`, not packages.

Answer (score 3):

Use `import static p1.Temp.*;` instead. The static *objects* you're trying to import aren't in the `p1` package but in the `p1.Temp` class.

**Edit after comments:**

In your `C:\java\static_import` folder, you have to have:

- a `p1` folder containing the `Temp.java` file;
- a `p2` folder containing the `StaticImport.java` file.

In the `StaticImport.java`, replace the `import static p1.Temp;` line by `import static p1.Temp.*;`.

Finally, using command lines:

```
cd C:\java\static_import
javac -d . p2/StaticImport.java
java p2/StaticImport
```

The output must be:

```
10
hello from show
10hello
```

Comment: hello thanks for answer but after changing the code  import static p1.Temp.*; program not working please give me some example please

Comment: @anil What do you mean by "not working"? In your `StaticImport.java` file, you replaced the `import static p1.Temp;` line by `import static p1.Temp.*;`, right?

Comment: @anil "program not working" isn't very descriptive. Please state what error do you get.

Comment: sorry but  after changing  import static p1.Temp; not working

Comment: @anil What isn't working? What error message(s) do you get? You'll have to give more details if you want us to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275124/how-to-static-import-user-define-class-in-other-package-in-java please see

Comment: @anil When you tried `import static p1.Temp.*;`, did you still have the same error message as before, i.e. the `cannot find symbol` messages?

Comment: @anil I edited my answer, please have a look. You must have a wrong file organization.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import all static classes in package p1, however Temp isn't static, thus it isn't imported. Just use a non-static import.